# How to extract the values for some specific index from a dataset

Tags: python, numpy

I have an indexlist say 
index=[0,2,3,4,7,8,10,11,12]
and for the above value of indexes, I want to take the value from the stored dataset and then append it to an empty array in a column manner
empty_array = np.empty((454902,))
how to do it?

Comment: Please give a bit more of context to your question. What is "the stored dataset", another NumPy array? What is the shape? What do you mean "append it to an empty array"? Can you give a small example of what kind of input and output you are thinking of?

Comment: That so called 'empty' array is not equivalent to an empty list, `[]`. Don't try it.

Comment: I think maybe you just need `dataset[:, index]`?

Comment: I have a dataset of shape (454902,30) and  have say 9 column indexes that is column_index=[0,2,3,4,7,8,10,11,12] and for these columns I want to append or store their corresponding values to an empty array .plz tell @jdehesa

Comment: @jdehesa has already answered your question in the previous comment.

Comment: I have tried  already in that away but it's not working so plz help